# Can Dwarf Carpet of Stars be planted on a balcony?

Tags: grass, succulents, patio

I want to build a grass box for approximately half of my balcony (~9’ x 6’) and grow Dwarf Carpet of Stars. I’m in zone 7a with morning shade/afternoon sun.

1. Is it possible to grow this succulent “grass” directly on top of a synthetic balcony floor?
2. Can it thrive in a relatively shallow container?
3. If so, what is the shallowest such a container could be for it to stay healthy?

I was hoping to place an impermeable membrane at the bottom, then layer on whatever rocks/soil is ideal for it to grow.

I really have my heart set on this plant because it would mimic grass while being really maintenance free. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you end up planting the dwarf carpet of starts?  How did it go?

Comment: I didn't. Everything I researched said it was probably not a good idea because of the weight. I don't know how much weight this balcony can handle.